# How to move/convert a method which is defined in our controller to its own restful route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

i just want to know how i can move my method from a get request to a specific controller where i can define it and use it in resources as restful route,
For example:
i have resources as:

```
resources: send_sms
get :new_sms to, send_sms#new_sms
```

i want that new_sms method to be done in my resources also. dont want to use get additionally.

My routes.rb

```
resources :send_sms, only: %i[index create]
get :new_sms, to: 'send_sms#new_sms'
```

here i want to move my new_sms to resources dont want to use this .. get `:new_sms`, to: `send_sms#new_sms`

My send_sms_controller.rb

```
class Admin::SendSmsController < AdminController
  before_action :authenticate_admin!
  before_action :user, only: %i[show edit new_sms kits_status]
  before_action :users, only: :index

  def show; end

  def index
    @users = users.search_by(params[:query]&.downcase)
  end

   #def new_sms; end


   def create

      client = Twilio::Client.new
      message = { to: user.phone_number,
                  body: params[:message] }
      client.send_message(message)
      redirect_to admin_users_path

   end
##################################################
my 
new_sms.slim
h2

  ="Send sms to #{@user.email}"
= simple_form_for(@user, url: admin_user_send_sms_path(@user), method: :post) do |f|
  section
  .form-inputs.column
    = text_area_tag 'message',nil, placeholder: 'write message here ...', size: "35x10"

  div#buttons
    =f.submit 'Send', class: 'btn btn-success'
    =link_to 'Cancel', admin_users_path, class: 'btn btn-danger'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define **member** routes in your resource

```
resources :send_sms, only: %i[index create] do
  member do
    get :new_sms 
  end
end
```

This will generate a **member** route 
 `get '/send_sms/:id/new_sms', to: 'send_sms#new_sms'`

Also you can define **collection** routes in your resource

```
resources :send_sms, only: %i[index create] do
  collection do
    get :new_sms 
  end
end
```

This will generate a **collection** route
 `get '/send_sms/new_sms', to: 'send_sms#new_sms'`

Comment: how i can just get rid of get?

Comment: i dont watnt o use get for new_sms

Comment: just want to move it into resources and from there call that new_sms